# Привязка к ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть несколько гридов. Все они скрыты до тех пор пока в `ComboBox`не выбрано `ComboBoxItem`. Когда выбираю один из `ComboBoxItem` должен появиться соответственно один из гридов. Привязку пытаюсь сделать в XAML без вью модели:

```
  <Grid x:Name="Cash" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=cmb_Security, Path=SelectedValue.Cash}" >
```

`Cash` это Item в Сombobox но сам грид виден независимо от того выбрано ли что то в боксе вообще. Как исправить это расширение разметки ?

Comment: `Visibility` должно иметь соответсвующие значения `Visible`, `Hidden` либо `Collapsed` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx)). Вы же непонятно на что вообще их биндите...

Comment: У свойства Visibility один тип,  у SelectedValue.Cash другой. Нужно добавить конвертер.

Comment: @AGS17 без вью модели не обойтись получается ?

Comment: Только если конвертером.

Comment: @Сергей, конвертер - это часть View, а не VM, если вы об этом ;)

Comment: можно использовать тригер с проверкой, что SelectedIndex == -1

Comment: написал ответ и надеюсь, я правильно понял вопрос, если что, то не стесняйтесь спрашивать - для более удобного и быстрого общения можете пинговать меня в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f)

Comment: А почему без VM? Это принципиально? С VM решение было бы намного правильнее.

Comment: @VladD не уверен что для такой мелочи вью модель стоит делать ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно такую задачу решают следующим образом.

1. У вас есть коллекция VM-объектов, каждый из которых содержит данные для своего грида и строки комбобокса.
2. Вы привязываете это коллекцию к `ItemsSource` комбобокса, устанавливаете `DisplayMemberPath` на то, что должно показываться в комбобоксе.
3. Для показа грида вы используете `Binding`, если все гриды одинаковые и отличаются только данными. Либо `ContentPresenter` и набор `DataTemplate`'ов, если они разные.

Пример:

VM-класс:

```
class ItemVM
{
    public string Header { get; }
    public string Content { get; }
    public ItemVM(string header, string сontent) { Header = header; Content = Content; }
}
```

Ну и обёртка для коллекции:

```
class MainVM
{
    public IEnumerable<ItemVM> Items { get; private set; }
    public ItemVM SelectedItem { get; set; }
    // ещё нужен конструктор
}
```

XAML (я тут показываю простой случай, с одинаковым лэйаутом для гридов):

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Header" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Items/}" Margin="10">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Результат:

[image: тестики, кому тестики, налетай]

---

Заметьте, что `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"` нужно лишь затем, чтобы сделать начальное значение в комбобоксе пустым. Больше это значение в коде не используется (хотя оно может вам понадобиться ещё где-нибудь в VM).

Comment: VladD, а почему не вариант с `Visibility`? Если бы `Grid` содержал больше различных элементов предложенное решение уже не сработало бы.

Comment: @sp7 почему не сработало-бы? это стандартное решение, только вместо `Grid` используют `ContentControl` - посмотрите ссылку на блог который приводил в своем ответе. Вариант с `Visibility` в данном случае на мой взгляд плохо подходит, так как он абсолютно не гибкий. Другими словами все элементы управления будут описываться в одном файле. Представьте как сложно будет с ним работать. Вариант с навигацией позволяет очень легко добавлять/удалять страницы и код четко разделен "по разделам"

Comment: Кстати в строке `Grid DataContext="{Binding Items/}"` случайно не опечатка, не должно ли там быть `Grid DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}"`?

Comment: @sp7 обратите внимание на `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`

Comment: Не совсем понял, как это работает. `MSDN` говорит что `Установка свойства IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" гарантирует, что выбранный элемент всегда задается как свойство CurrentItem`. Собственно не понятно, что это за `CurrentItem` откуда он берется то вообще и почему элементы из `StackPanel` смотрят данные в  нем?

Comment: @sp7: Ну как бы да, если бы в гриде были фиксированные элементы, приходилось бы ещё триггер на `Grid.DataContext == null` навесить.

Comment: @sp7: Не, не опечатка, работает же :) `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` работает так: на коллекцию, являющуюся `ItemsSource`'ом, неявно надевается CollectionView. В нём есть понятие `CurrentItem`, которое неявно привязывается к выбранному в списке элементу (при `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem == true`). А `/` в `Binding` и означает `CurrentItem`.

Comment: @sp7: То есть для случая если в VM есть `SelectedItem`, это то же самое. Но если в VM такого нету, а вам хочется привязаться к выбранному элементу, поможет трюк с `/`.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, разъяснили как это работает. Т.е. как такового преимущества способ с `/` не дает, за исключением того, что позволяет избежать создания `SelectedItem` в `VM`?

Comment: @sp7: Ну я разницы не знаю, может, кто-то подскажет ещё.

Answer (score 4):

В вашем вопросе на мой взгляд содержаться два отдельных.

Первый - это как отображать элемент только в том случае, когда есть выбранный элемент. Эту проблему можно решить с помощью триггера с проверкой на то, что `SelectedIndex` != `-1`. Простейший пример:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Name="some"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Margin="10"
                  MinWidth="120"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=some}" Margin="10">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=some, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

для полноты примера привожу тривиальный контекст для данных

```
module Context2 = 
    open Gjallarhorn.Bindable

    let create() =    
        let source = Binding.createSource()

        [|"Some1"; "Some2" ; "Some3" |]
        |> Binding.constantToView "Data" <| source

        source
```

Второй - как в зависимости от выбранного элемента в списке отобразить соответствующие данные. Если вкратце - вы создаете список из "страничных" VM и привязываете его к вашему `ComboBox`. Выбранный элемент вы можете непосредственно отображать в `ContentControl` через привязку к SelectedItem или завести свойство в основной VM которое и будет отвечать за выбранную `VM`.

На этот счет есть замечательная статья [Navigation with MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/), где вы можете прочитать об этом подходе более подробно, а также посмотреть на реализацию простого примера.