# Обработчик событий для конкретного item в combmbox

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть combobox - содержащий в себе некие item - меню короче.
Необходимо для каждого их этих item сделать отдельный обработчик событий - т.е по щелчку на каждый из них - они должный выполнять разные дейсвия.
Я пытался сделать так:
Сделал одно общее стандартное событие MouseLeftButtonDown

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxMenu" Width="74" Height="20" Text="Файл"
          MouseLeftButtonDown="ComboBoxMenu_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
```

и обработчик для него:

```
private void ComboBoxMenu_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender,MouseButtonEventArgs e)        
{
    var p= ComboBox.ItemsSource.GetEnumerator();
    var c= p.Current;
    var d= c as ComboBoxItem;
    d.MouseLeftButtonDown += D_MouseLeftButtonDown;
}
```

где уже в этом обработчике, подписываю текущий элемент коллекции на другой обработчик  - в котором и будет происходить вся логика:

```
private void D_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //вся логика
}
```

Правильно ли я поступаю или есть какой - то другой подход?

Comment: И что должно происходить когда вы выберете очередной элемент списка?

Comment: должен срабатывать конкретно его обработчик события  - когда его выбрали.

Comment: Ну вообще ComboBox - это выпадающий список и при клике на его элементе происходит событие SelectionChanged, в нем нельзя действие сделать?

Comment: т.е правильно будет через SelectionChanged -?

Comment: А почему вы разрабатываете `WPF` приложение и не используете `MVVM` паттерн?

Comment: потому что я не знаком с паттернами, ну наверное кроме mvp и то косвенно

Comment: Ну тогда подпишитесь на `SelectionChanged` как вам и писали и реализуйте нужную логику там.

Comment: @BadCats: ну вы бы разобрались с MVVM. Это ведущий способ писать WPF-приложения. И там проблем, подобных вашей, не возникает.

Comment: Вы наверное хотите в зависимости от выбранного элемента показывать различные элементы?

Comment: да, именно так. Обработчик я уже нашел:
 ListBoxItem lbi = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
теперь нужно сделать if проверку на позицию lbi ?

Comment: Такой вопрос уже задавался и не раз, вот из последнего - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676775/Привязка-к-comboboxitem/677086

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Привязка к ComboBoxItem](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676775/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba-comboboxitem)

Comment: я уже понял, но спасибо за ссылку - сейчас почитаю.

Comment: если что-то будет непонятно не стесняйтесь спрашивать